# Getting Razor View to understand Linq to SQL objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I would like to loop through a result in a view from a call to a LINQ to SQL function that returns a list of objects. However, I am not sure how to get the view to handle the L2S object (in order to use a foreach).

In the controller:

```
  ViewData["list"] = db.Users.ToList();
```

Comment: View is not the right place to do this. You should do it in your model.

Comment: Have scaffolding generate this for you, if you need an example to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller:

```
public class MyClassController : Controller
{
    private ProjectContext db = new ProjectContext();

    //
    // GET: /MyClass/

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.MyClasses.ToList());
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.MyClass>


@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <div>
    <!-- HTML here like @item.Title -->
    </div>
}
```

This is the strongly typed view methodology.  Using the dynamic approach it isn't much different.  Just assigning your list to a property on the dynamic object and then instead of `foreach(var item in Model)` it becomes `foreach(var item in ViewBag.listProperty)`.  Or with ViewData you assign `ViewData.Add('list', db.MyClasses.ToList())` and the foreach becomes `foreach(var item in ViewData['list'])`  I prefer the strongly typed approach as it seems much much cleaner.

EDIT: good point brought up in comments (that I forgot since I almost exclusively use the strongly typed approach) is that you'll have to cast out.  In this case it is stored as a `List<MyClass>` though you can also implicitly pull it out as an `IEnumerable<MyClass>`

Comment: But in the dynamic case you have to cast the ViewData['list']. And here I am not sure to what type to cast it to.

Comment: @Jason: `List<MyClass>`  Or (probably) in your case `List<User>`.  You can always cast it to the interface `IEnumerable<T>` where T is your entity class too. (`IEnumerable<User>`)