# InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, .net-4.0

So I am try to pass some linq data from my controller to my view much like [Getting Razor View to understand Linq to SQL objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886143/getting-razor-view-to-understand-linq-to-sql-objects)

but I get an InvalidCastException every time my controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Account()
    {
        return View(data.FailitatorParentLists.ToList());
    }
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
[InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String() +5271065
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 i) +75
Read_FacilitatorParentList(ObjectMaterializer`1 ) +2677
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext() +32
System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +381
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
Omega.Controllers.ParentsController.Account(String returnUrl) in    c:\Users\chrism\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Omega\Omega- Source\Omega\Controllers\ParentsController.cs:38
lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +180
System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +59
System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +435
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +60
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +50
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +75
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +44
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +139
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +126
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +323
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +139
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +68
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +184
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +136
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +151
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +151
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +151
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9629296
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Here are the Linq to SQL definition Properties

```
    private System.Nullable<int> _UserID;

    private int _StaffLocalID;

    private string _Fac;

    private string _StaffFirstName;

    private string _StaffLastName;

    private string _StaffEmail;

    private string _AcademyID;

    private int _StudentID;

    private string _StudentLastName;

    private string _StudentFirstName;

    private System.Nullable<short> _Grade;

    private string _ParentID;

    private string _parentemail;

    private System.Nullable<int> _ParentUserID;

    private string _ParentLastName;

    private string _ParentFirstName;

    private string _Relationship;
```

Comment: Could you show the stack trace? What operation exactly causes exception?

Comment: Do you have any `int` fields in your database that are mapped to `string` fields in your model?

Comment: Please post the definition of `Read_FacilitatorParentList` (properties only) and the structure of your table.

Comment: I just checked all the mappings and there isn't any int being incorrectly mapped or vice versa.

Comment: Where would I find the definition of Read_FacilitatorParentList it doesnt appear to be in the autogenerated Linq to SQL code?

Comment: Sorry should be `FacilitatorParent` or `FacilitatorParentList` (took the method name from the stack trace)

Comment: You'll need to show us the query used in `data.FailitatorParentLists`.  Apparently you're doing an invalid cast there and the `ToList()` call is merely exposing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it! the issues was my dba had change the type of a column and did not inform me. lol!

Comment: In that case, when you commented on your question "I just checked all the mappings and there isn't any int being incorrectly mapped or vice versa.", how did you check? If you include how you checked, and how you should have checked, this answer may be useful for others too.

Comment: I just over looked the column.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and in my case I had to change the VS Project setting to build for x64 instead of Any

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31901290)